# Generate and export an animated gif via Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, image-processing, gif, swift3, animated-gif

I've learned that the Image IO Framework has changed syntactically since iOS 9 according to the documentation, however I have done my research and the following code *seems* to be correct. I have to procedures listed below; one procedure takes images and writes those images to the application's document folder as a gif. I can confirm this works as I can view the actually gif file if I go to the app's documents folder using iTunes. Despite this, in the second procedure where I attempt to read from that same file, an error is throw which states the file at that path does not exist. I have posted the code below.

```
class GifManager {
private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL?  {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
}

public func generateGif(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {
    if let docsDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory() {
        let url = docsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
        let gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.125]]
        if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil) {
            CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
            for photo in photos {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
            }
            return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        }
    }
    return false
}

public func saveGifToCameraRoll(filename: String) {
    if let docsDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory() {
        let fileUrl: URL = docsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            if let _ = UIImage(data: data) {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: fileUrl)
                    }, completionHandler: {completed, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error")
                        } else if completed {
                            print("completed")
                        } else {
                            print("not completed")
                        }
                })
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you saying you can use your `generateGif` function to write a GIF file, but not your `saveGifToCameraRoll` to put it in the Photos library? Photos doesn't support GIFs.

Comment: I actually got it to work. The gif file is saved to photos, and although the gif file doesn't play in photos, you can mms the gif itself and it will play on the recipient device. This works for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Photos stores whatever file you put into it but doesn't promise to keep it intact. You might not get a GIF on the other end after iCloud Photo Library sync, and editing in the Photos app will definitely replace it with a JPEG. Possibly other issues, too: hence "doesn't support", even if you can kinda get it to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Swift 3.1, 4 and 5**

For those wanting an updated version of the GIF generation function, I have included it here.

This function requires the `ImageIO` and `MobileCoreServices` import statements.

```
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices
```

Here is the function.

```
func generateGif(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {
    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let path = documentsDirectoryPath.appending(filename)
    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
    let gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.125]]
    let cfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL
    if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfURL, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil) {
            CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
            for photo in photos {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
            }
            return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        }
    return false
}
```

**EDIT:**

It has a `Bool` so you know you can safely use the file it creates.

```
if generateGif(arrayOfImages, "/myGIFfile.gif") {
    // do something with gif
} else {
    // failed to create and close the gif file
}
```

Comment: why is it returning a bool?

Comment: The `Bool` to make sure that the file is created and has been closed successfully. I've updated my answer to include how to use it.

Comment: and where is the generated gif?

Comment: nevermind. i have been able to use your code for a work around for my needs. thank you

Comment: @skymook how to use that gif in `UIImageView`??

Comment: @YashR it is likely you would need to run this gif in a `UIWebview`, but there are libraries out there you that will support gif like SwiftGif:  https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif

Comment: @skymook how to view this in `UIWebView`?

Comment: @skymook can u show me how to get this gif from directory to `UIWebView`?I am new in iOS Development

Comment: @YashR There are many answer to that question on StackOverflow, and the others you are asking. It wouldn't be too much to search for the answer, or read up how getting files works in Apple's documentation. Sorry, but your comment is not related to this post about creating gifs.

Comment: @skymook i have asked one question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434727/swift-3-how-to-get-gif-from-document-directory

Comment: Memory usage reached 1.4gb (Simulator), in real device app crashing due memory issue How we can reduce memory usage?

Comment: @CoderACJHP Maybe you can't. The larger the image array, the more memory you use. Maybe the only solution is only process small image array.